# Angular proxy not working

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I use `spring mvc` which work on port **8080** and `angular 5` so i try this configuration so that the client at 4200 will proxy any /api requests to the server.

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/NG-PROJETS",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

I Edit package.json file for “start” script:

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   
 }
```

But when i try

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('/api/new-projet').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

I run angular server:

```
PS C:\Users\Yous\Desktop\NG-DEV\projets> ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-12-18T11:27:05.809Z
Hash: b7bab060a44cd3aad50d
Time: 6395ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 49.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 550 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 34.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.47 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

I get this error in the chrome console
`GET http://localhost:4200/api/new-projet 404 (Not Found)`
So where is the problem ?

P.S the url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/NG-PROJETS/new-projet` works fine.

Comment: add star  `"*/api*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/NG-PROJETS",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```